# Drupal 7 Adding Page with different template of page

Tags: drupal

I am not experience, can smbd show the way. I need give possibility to simple user to create Page and he need to have possibility in select area choose Templates type for the page which he is create. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create multiple Content Types and give them the names of the templates you want to offer. 
Then, you'll need to create those templates, you should probably use node.tpl.php as a base.

After you're done with a template you can save it in the templates folder (/sites/all/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/) and name it like node--mycontenttype.tpl.php

Note that you'll need two dashes (--) after the word node in the filename. For more information on designing templates for Drupal, please refer to https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme